# I installed mysql 5.1 from the official site, but am having issues

Tags: mysql, installation, environment

NOTE: I am using Mac OS X Lion

Two issues in particular:

1) The server won't start when I try to start it from the pref pane

2) I get this error when I type "mysql" in the command line. ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

When I type mysqld, I get the following error:

120328 17:28:55 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.1.62-osx10.6-x86_64/data/Shaans-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
120328 17:28:55 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.1.62-osx10.6-x86_64/data/Shaans-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/usr/local/mysql-5.1.62-osx10.6-x86_64/data/' (Errcode: 13)
120328 17:28:55 [ERROR] Aborting

120328 17:28:55 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

When I type "sudo mysqld", I get the following error:

120328 17:45:48 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-5.1.62-osx10.6-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
120328 17:45:48 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

120328 17:45:48 [ERROR] Aborting

120328 17:45:48 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

When I type "sudo mysqld_safe", I get the following response:

120328 17:50:26 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Shaans-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
120328 17:50:26 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
120328 17:50:32 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/Shaans-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqld` to start the server - `mysql` starts the command line interface, not the daemon.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Ubuntu? Try `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`.

EDIT: mysql, not mysqld

Comment: As noted by @user1299241, it looks like directly invoking init.d scripts is deprecated in Ubuntu. It will still work, but the accepted method now is using `service`.

Comment: Hey I'm actually using mac os x

Comment: `sudo mysqld` should do the trick, then. (Of course I see the MacBook reference after the fact).

Comment: Erm, I now see your paste when you try to sudo it. What happens if you try `sudo mysqld_safe`?

Comment: Just pasted the response. What do you think?

Comment: Looks like it's working - try firing up `mysql -u root -p` (enter whatever root password you chose during setup for MySQL) and see if it's working.

Comment: it asked for a password, I'm not sure I gave one during setup though. When I input the password I believe it is, I get the following response: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Hmmm...a glance at the MySQL docs makes it look like the GRANT tables lack passwords after installation on OS X. Try just `mysql -u root` instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9431/discussion-between-todd-b-and-shaan)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what distro you have, these commands may work, I use Ubuntu Server 10.04

I type:
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service mysql start
sudo service mysql restart

To perform those functions

Comment: I think the /etc/init.d/mysql start command that Todd B suggested will work.  However, when I do it, it gives this warning message
`Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start`
So I started using the sudo service mysql start